# MVC controller injection with custom base controller not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

I am using StructureMap for DI and am having an issue with my MVC3 custom base controller not being instantiated correctly. Instead of being passed an instance of IAuctionCmsServices, I am getting null.

My controllers:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IAuctionCmsServices AuctionCmsServices;

    public BaseController()
        : this(null)        <--- is this the problem?
    {

    }

    public BaseController(IAuctionCmsServices auctionCmsServices)
    {
        this.AuctionCmsServices = auctionCmsServices;
    }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View);
    }
}
```

StructureMap code:

```
public class StructureMapContainer : IDependencyResolver
{
    static IContainer _container;

    public StructureMapContainer(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
        {
            return _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_container.WhatDoIHave());
            return _container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances<object>().Where(s => s.GetType() == serviceType);
    }
}

public class ApplicationRegistry : Registry
{
    public ApplicationRegistry()
    {
        For<IAuctionCmsServices>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<AuctionCmsServices>();
    }
}
```

In global.asax.cs:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapContainer(container));
```

When BaseController's constructor is invoked, the IAuctionCmsServices parameter is null. If I remove the this(null) from the constructor, I still get null.

Perhaps my BaseController's paramterless constructor is not written correctly? If I resolve for IAuctionCmsServices manually, it works. This means that IAuctionCmsServices is registered correctly but not being injected.

Comment: I know this might not be a helpful comment, but why not NinJect?

Comment: You're right, not helpful. I don't think the container is the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you leave out the constructor HomeController from the sample or do you not have one?

Im not really familiar with StructureMap, so unless it does some wizardry with the IL, how is the property supposed to be injected into HomeController if it does not have a constructor that accepts it?

IE

```
public HomeController(IAuctionCmsServices auctionCmsServices)
 : base(auctionCmsServices)
{}
```

Apologies if Im being dense or missing something.

Comment: HomeController inherits from BaseController. I wanted to use a custom base controller so I wouldn't have to spread the same constructor code among numerous controllers.

Comment: Again, unless StructureMap has IL weaving features im not aware of, then there is not point in you having the parameterized constructor in the base class if no deriving classes are going to use it. If the constructor on the derived class does not call the constructor on the base class then the base constructor cannot possibly be called. E.G if you delete your parameterless constructor on the BaseController, your code will not compile. 

You will have to use property injection instead of constructor injection in order to get the results you desire.

Comment: I was just arriving at that same judgement. Thank you.